# Google Blogger News Feed for Website

Tags: web, blogs, blogger

I have a website and a google blogger site in conjunction.  I would like to add a section to my website home page that displays the 3 or 4 most recent blog posts (post title and the first 100-200 words of the post).

Is there a widget that will do this or any suggestion on how to set this up?

Thanks!

Comment: "A widget"?  Are you looking to write code for this, or just use some configurable component of the services you're using?  If the latter, you might try webapps.stackexchange.com instead.  If you're looking to write code for it, you'll need to give us more information.  JavaScript only?  (Might run into a same origin policy problem.)  Server-side code?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess I was hoping someone could suggest the right method to get this task accomplished, either through code or widget. I know that word press has some easy widgets that will do this but I dont know if anything like that exists for blogger.  Sorry I cant provide more details, I just dont know myself.

Comment: No PHP solution is here, you can find work around here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943544/how-to-parse-an-rss-feed-using-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a really useful tutorial that does exactly what I want very easily.  Inputs the post title, date/time of the entry, and the first 150 characters in the post.  Very easy to set up. 
http://alt-web.blogspot.com/2011/06/adding-blogger-rss-feed-to-html-page.html
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing a short PHP script to print out the first 4 items from the RSS feed...

Answer (score 0):

Check out feedburner. https://feedburner.google.com/

Specifically, look at the BuzzBoost option under publicize. This allows you to embed javascript in your HTML that will generate HTML of your last few posts.