# Chrome extension parsing RSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, rss-reader, jfeed

I'm working on an extension for Chrome that uses an RSS parser, however I have used several different methods and I keep getting the error: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load Example.rss. Origin chrome extension://djhppbppokfmldecpcfbcmchagimpmpc is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Tried using the AJAX feed and jFeed methods in the first answer below but neither worked for me.

[How to parse an RSS feed using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943544/how-to-parse-a-rss-feed-using-javascript)

Here's my JavaScript function:

```
   jQuery.getFeed({
   url: 'http://example.rss',
   success: function(feed) {
       alert(feed.title);
   }});
```

My Manifest.JSON looks like

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"version": "1.0",
"permissions": ["http://*/", "tabs"],
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the url for the feed? Try adding a `*` to the end of `http://*/` so that it becomes `http://*/*`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CSP in your manifest.
Something like this line, but change example.com to your feed:

```
content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://example.com; object-src 'self'
```

For more read this: [CSP in Chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your specified host permission is missing a `path`.

Change `http://*/` to `http://*/*`

For more info, see the chrome documentation on [match patterns](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html).