# Parce BBC RSS feed with JS

Tags: javascript, rss, web.xml

I am making small website and I need to use [this](http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/europe/rss.xml) link to take news feed from there and put it in my website. How can I pars this news (title, text and image) and display it right on my website?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943544/how-to-parse-a-rss-feed-using-javascript This answer is very comprehensive

Comment: I have already try this answer and non of it examples worked for me...

Comment: Well which bits don't work for you? What have you tried? What code is failing?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AFL9j/


XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/europe/rss.xml. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
And can you tell me is it somehow possible to extract news text even even though it is not in .xml file?

Answer (score 0):

1. User server side language to download the external xml contents
2. Use jQuery.parseXML to parse it
3. In PHP there is SimpleXML library where you can use to convert the XML to array or objects. Then convert the array or object to json.