# Yahoo weather rss feed parsing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

I am trying to parse Yahoo weather RSS feed using jquery.

I am using this code from [How to parse an RSS feed using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943544/how-to-parse-a-rss-feed-using-javascript)

```
$.get('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2502265', function(data) {
        $(data).find("channel").each(function() {
            var el = $(this);

            console.log("------------------------");
            console.log("title      : " + el.find("title").text());
            console.log("description: " + el.find("description").text());
        });
    });
```

Now in Firebug console this line is shown in red

```
GET http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2502265 200 OK 1.84s
```

and if i expand this i am getting an error under xml tab

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{b89cceaa-43a2-4015-b9cf-578d1ce6afee} Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/a/226679/3440995

Comment: Could yo try to log the `data` variable as well?

Comment: i tried `console.log(data)` . but nothing got logged.