# Parse specifiic rss item

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, rss

I'm trying to parse specific pieces of entire rss feeds - I'm thinking that I need to use arrays, but plugins don't appear to provide it, and I'm not enough of a coder to understand how to do it.  Right now, I have duplicate pieces of HTML to display the first two divs, but I'm not sure how to select the correct feeds. Here's one section for reference - I'm not looking for exact code, but to understand what I'm looking for:

```
<article>
    <div class="date"><span>Dec</span>
      <br/> 24</div>
      <div class="content">
      <h3><a href="maintenance/maintenance-page.html">Title</a></h3>
      <p class="small">Blurb</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a RSS feed using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943544/how-to-parse-a-rss-feed-using-javascript)

Comment: Kind of, but I want to parse the feed out of order.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
var item = feed.items[i];
```

in the jFeed library specifies the item number.