# how to create an rss feed from a third party, web page

Tags: html, rss

Background: there is an external web page from a non-profitable organization that publish mp3 audio files and I'd like to subscribe the page in a podcast listener, but the lack of RSS prevents that.

Solution(?): parse that web page in weekly basis and create an RSS feed somewhere else with the audio files.

Parsing HTML would be easy, but creating the RSS and specially where to create it are the main concerns, as I don't have blog accounts, personal sites, etc.

Tks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse an RSS feed using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943544/how-to-parse-an-rss-feed-using-javascript)

Comment: not really. The article suggested asks for a way to parse an existing RSS feed and get its content. My question is the opposite - having a existing, 3rd party HTML page, how to create an RSS pointing to their audio files.

Answer (score 1):

There are services like http://feed43.com/ that can produce feeds from pages, but you have to "costruct" your feed extractor explaining what is relevant to you

Comment: tks for the tip, It looked perfect but I faced some issues (see answer below)

Comment: Thanks, found this service very useful!

Answer (score 0):

The http://feed43.com/ was tried (tks for the tip) but its free mode allows parsing web pages whose size is up to 100Kb. The page I need to process is larger, of corse. But Feed43 provides the RSS for the itens up to 100Kb, what is a good reference.

I used it as a template to create the RSS by myself in my computer. After that, I uploaded the RSS to Google Sites (created a File Cabinet to hold random files).

RSS syntax was checked by http://feedvalidator.org/, which found some inconsistencies in the template (duplicated GUIDs, etc). RSS file was fixed (removed all GUID tags), uploaded and voila, finally I get a podcast version for the site.

I hope it helps.