# Fetch RSS data from different website without PHP

Tags: javascript, html, css, rss

I'm working on a website (www.vandaagapple.nl), and I'm trying to get the following to work: I'm having a blog on nieuws.vandaagapple.nl, and I'm trying to display the latest ten articles on our main page, www.vandaagapple.nl. Until now, I've used an iframe, but as you might know, these are a bit limited and not so good for SEO.

Now I am looking for the following solution: I want to fetch the RSS items like the Title, Description and Image for each of the last ten articles. Is there a way to fetch these, and show them on the main page of my website? My server can't handle PHP, so I can only use html, css, javascript.

Other solution might be to fetch the .div that belongs to each post's title, description and image, but don't think that's possible.

I've tried a lot but haven't found anything working. The format I'm using right now, for the iframe is the following:

```
<style type="text/css">

                                #inieuwsartikelen{
                                width:100%;
                                height:6300px;
                                border:0px solid #000; 
                                overflow:hidden;
                                margin-bottom:-110px;
                                padding-top: -113px;
                                }
                                #inieuwsartikelen iframe {
                                width:100%;
                                height:100%;
                                margin-top:-160px;
                                border: none;
                                margin-left: -20px;
                                }

                                </style>

                                <div id="inieuwsartikelen">
                                    <iframe scrolling="no" src=
                                    "http://nieuws.vandaagapple.nl/">  </iframe>
                                </div>
```

The iframe works, but at the bottom of the iframe it never shows exactly an article but often just the half of it, which makes it very ugly.

Comment: Try posting some code showing what you have already tried

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but I think you need to allow CORS on your server.

Some readings about fetching feed using js: [How to parse an RSS feed using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943544/how-to-parse-an-rss-feed-using-javascript)