# Is It possible with Github Pages to consume/parse data from a third party (cross-origin) RSS feed?

Tags: rss, jekyll, github-pages

I would like to create a webpage that displays the data from another website's RSS feed and prettify the content and maybe remove some entries etc.

Is this something that would be possible with Github pages and jekyl?

I suspect not but I'm a little out of date with the latest web-tech so would appreciate any advice.

(I am unable to do this with javascript/ajax alone because the request is cross-origin and I get "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at X" errors.)

Thanks

**For Example**

Let's say i want to create page at https://news.github.io that when requested fetches the data from the BBC's RSS news feed at http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=uk and displays the title of the first 10 results in a table with a given font.

Comment: This is quite vague. Which RSS ? What type of content ? What do you call prettify ? How do you want to filter entries ? Can you give some code examples ?

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity. I've added a completely contrived example.

Comment: Your problem is not related to jekyll nor github pages. You can integrate to your generated pages a javascript code to parse the RSS feed when the pages are loaded, which leads to this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943544/how-to-parse-an-rss-feed-using-javascript)

Comment: I don't believe I can achieve this with javascript alone because the cross-origin request gets blocked by the browser.