# Convert console.log to output to a div

Tags: jquery, html, rss

I'm using simple rss feed parser example from this topic = [Rss Parser Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943544/how-to-parse-an-rss-feed-using-javascript).

```
$.get('https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/10943544', function (data) {
    $(data).find("entry").each(function () { // or "item" or whatever suits your feed
        var el = $(this);

        console.log("------------------------");
        console.log("title      : " + el.find("title").text());
        console.log("author     : " + el.find("author").text());
        console.log("description: " + el.find("description").text());
    });
});
```

---

Its perfect, however I want to show each output log in a specific div, eg:

title log goes in to a `<div class="Rss-Title"></div>` and so on. So at the end I should have something like this:

```
<div id="Rss">

<div class="Rss-Title"></div>

<div class="Rss-Author"></div>

<div class="Rss-Description"></div>

</div>
```

My question: whats a proper way to do something like that?

Comment: Do you want to do log entries into a div?

Comment: Not clear: can you change the source?  Your title+question do not match.

Comment: Sorry for being uclear guys. Ish alrdy posted the answer.

Comment: No worries - glad you got your answer.  I've taken the liberty of updating the question title to better reflect the issue for future searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function

```
<div id="Rss">

<div class="Rss-Title"></div>

<div class="Rss-Author"></div>

<div class="Rss-Description"></div>

</div>

$.get('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/10943544', function (data) {
 $(data).find("entry").each(function () { // or "item" or whatever suits your feed
    var el = $(this);

    $('#Rss-Title').html(el.find("title").text());
    $('#Rss-Author').html(el.find("author").text());
    $('#Rss-Description').html(el.find("description").text());
 });
});
```

Comment: This is what I meant. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of console.log, you select the element and place text inside by using `html()` (or as alternative `text()`)

```
$.get('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/10943544', function (data) {
    $(data).find("entry").each(function () { // or "item" or whatever suits your feed
        var el = $(this);
        $('.Rss-Title').html("title      : " + el.find("title").text());
        $('.Rss-Author').html("author     : " + el.find("author").text());
        $('.Rss-Description').html("description: " + el.find("description").text());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, will try both - urs and Ish's.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly unclear from the title/question what the issue is, so this answer is for:

> Console.log in to a div

The "proper" way to do this would be to change the source that does the console.log

To change the console.log to go to a div instead, you can re-write console.log, eg:

```
console.log("test1")
window.console.log = function(txt) { 
    //alert(txt)
    $("#log").text($("#log").text() + txt);
}
console.log("test2")
```

Comment: Sorry for being uclear. Ish alrdy posted the answer. This is what I meant.