# Read news from feed using jquery (cross domain), Getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, jsonp

I am trying to read yahoo news feed from SharePoint site and its a cross domain access. I am using mentioned code to access but getting below error, I have gone thru lots of sites and blogs but still no luck. (I am running this code in Chrome console)

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

```
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"https://www.yahoo.com/news/rss/world",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

[image]

Please suggest!

Comment: Is the day you are getting from the API JSON

Comment: have you tried to remove the datatype ?
im sure of that the type will not be json

Comment: Why not use an RSS feed reader rather than making a GET request? See some suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943544/how-to-parse-an-rss-feed-using-javascript

Comment: try to use other alternatives of Google API Feed to get rss data

Comment: @Rishi Jagati, Check my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Google API Feed** is already deprecated.So try to use alternative like **rss2json** site to read rss that convert to json.

```
http://rss2json.com/
```

Example:

put your rss url like below

```
url: "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=" + "https://www.yahoo.com/news/rss/world",
```

Code

```
var url= 'https://www.yahoo.com/news/rss/world';
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=" + url,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data.feed.description);    
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/yvzSL/1406/

I think it should helps you

Comment: Loved it! I am surprised I was not aware of this. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see from the API, the data present is not json and hence you get the the following error

Change the dataType to `xml`

```
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"https://www.yahoo.com/news/rss/world",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

However you may face the `CORS` error if the API doesnt' have Access control headers set

Comment: True, it gives me CORS error. How can I achieve this?
Do I need to go for another feed which support json dataType?

Comment: You need to go for an API that has Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers set  for its website or you need to request for the same. XML or JSON data won't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting Cors origin , access denied or you are not allowed to get these data,
the best choice will be Parsing the data after hitting an http get request by server side and then load it in your HTML page
So the steps will be

1. The ajax will request a local file
2. then server side (local file which you requested) will do an http get request in order to pull the page
3. this will get the whole of page, you can get your data by knowing the tags of you data
4. finally parse your data yo json object and pass it to your ajax request