# How to parse an RSS feed using JavaScript (External Domain)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, rss

**Question**

I need to parse an RSS feed and display the parsed details in an HTML page.

**Solution I Found**

[How to parse an RSS feed using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943544/how-to-parse-an-rss-feed-using-javascript) is a very similar question and I followed it.

Using above question, I build the following code.

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //feed to parse
    var feed = "https://feeds.feedburner.com/raymondcamdensblog?format=xml";

    $.ajax(feed, {
        accepts:{
            xml:"application/rss+xml"
        },
        dataType:"xml",
        success:function(data) {
            //Credit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943544/how-to-parse-an-rss-feed-using-javascript

            $(data).find("item").each(function () { // or "item" or whatever suits your feed
                var el = $(this);
                document.write("------------------------");
                document.write("title      : " + el.find("title").text());
                document.write("link       : " + el.find("link").text());
                document.write("description: " + el.find("description").text());
            });


        }   
    });

});
</script>
```

**The Error**

> Failed to load
>   https://feeds.feedburner.com/raymondcamdensblog?format=xml: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

**What I need**

How can I change my code to read RSS feeds using JavaScript without getting above error?

Comment: To respond precisely your question: How can I change my code to read RSS feeds using JavaScript without getting above error? Unfortunately, there is nothing we can do with JavaScript (in browsers), except if you have a browser older than these https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin#Browser_compatibility because the restriction is made by the browsers.

Answer (score 7):

You could use something like https://rss2json.com.
It parses the feed to json for javascript:

```
var feedURL = "https://feeds.feedburner.com/raymondcamdensblog?format=xml";
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=" + feedURL,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You're getting that error because of the [**same-origin policy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). See below and/or read the full article at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS):

> For *security reasons*, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests
>   initiated from within scripts. For example, `XMLHttpRequest` and the
>   Fetch API follow the same-origin policy. This means that a web
>   application using those APIs can only request HTTP resources *from the
>   same origin* the application was loaded from, *unless* the response
>   from the other origin includes the right *CORS headers*.

So your script is making a **cross-origin HTTP request** (which uses `XMLHttpRequest` through `jQuery.ajax()`) to https://feeds.feedburner.com/raymondcamdensblog?format=xml, but the CORS header of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not being set by FeedBurner, therefore you get the "Failed to load ..." error. (But even if the header was set, if it didn't include your *origin* (`localhost` or `some-domain.com`), you'd still get the same error.)

**So how can *you* change your code to read the RSS feeds using JavaScript without getting that error?**

1. Use a third-party web service, just like what @[Saeed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5939933/saeed) suggested.
2. Create a server-side script (e.g. using PHP) that fetches the feed content and make AJAX requests to that script instead of *directly* requesting it from FeedBurner, or the actual source URL. See below for a simple example.
3. If I really had to, I'd probably ask FeedBurner to set the appropriate CORS headers...

---

**Sample of a *very simple* PHP script for fetching the feed content:**

```
<?php
// Set the feed URL.
$feed_url = 'https://feeds.feedburner.com/raymondcamdensblog?format=xml';

// Fetch the content.
// See http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php for more
// information about the file_get_contents() function.
$content = file_get_contents( $feed_url );

// Set the Content-Type header.
header( 'Content-Type: application/rss+xml' );

// Display the content and exit.
echo $content;
exit;
?>
```

So for example, you could save that to `fetch-feed.php`, and then in your JavaScript/jQuery script code, change the value of the `feed` variable like so:

```
var feed = "http://localhost/path/to/fetch-feed.php";
```

That way (i.e. using your own server-side script), you could *at least* be sure that the browser would always grant your `XMLHttpRequest` (or AJAX) request. (i.e. you wouldn't get the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" error)

Comment: Thanks. It is just not about FeedBurner , there are lot of sites. I have something like AllTop site. I have the PHP script. But the problem is when there are lot of feeds it uses lot of server resources. That's why I thought to use JS, so I can save server resources. Seems like now only solution is using third party service.

Comment: You can leverage *caching* from within your PHP script. And if you're doing the fetching from WordPress, you can utilize their transients and caching API, and there are also plugins like [WP RSS Agregator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-aggregator/) which does RSS fetching, parsing, etc. pretty well. But this stuff seems to be out of the question's scope. So if you need further help, I suggest you to ask a new question specific to PHP and RSS/feeds.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [jquery-rss](https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss) or [Vanilla RSS](https://github.com/sdepold/vanilla-rss), which comes with nice templating and is super easy to use:

```
// Example for jquery.rss
$("#your-div").rss("https://feeds.feedburner.com/raymondcamdensblog?format=xml", {
    limit: 3,
    layoutTemplate: '<ul class="inline">{entries}</ul>',
    entryTemplate: '<li><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a><br/>{shortBodyPlain}</li>'
})

// Example for Vanilla RSS
const RSS = require('vanilla-rss');
const rss = new RSS(
    document.querySelector("#your-div"),
    "https://feeds.feedburner.com/raymondcamdensblog?format=xml",
    { 
      // options go here
    }
);
rss.render().then(() => {
  console.log('Everything is loaded and rendered');
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sdepold/ozq2dn9e/1/ for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

It's a CORS related error. You are getting that error because the URL from where you are requesting data does not have **CORS** enabled. CORS stands for 'Cross-Origin Resource Sharing'. If CORS is enabled on a server, your browser will let you make requests to that server. Otherwise, it will not.

`https://feeds.feedburner.com/raymondcamdensblog?format=xml` does not have CORS enabled, that's why your **browser** will not allow you to make ajax requests to that server. You can get around it by making the requests on your server and provide the data to the browser from your own server or a server that has CORS enabled.