# How do you get XML data from RSS feeds starting with “feed://“ using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rss, feed, nwjs

I am inside of NW.JS and I need to be able to get RSS feeds but can currently only retrieve data from some xml feeds, not all. I think my problem might be CORS. I have tried "setting headers" in my ajax but the nw.js browser refuses to set them.

I have already tried ajax like this...

```
var cleanURL = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/uk/rss.xml"
$(document).ready(function() {
//feed to parse
var feed = cleanURL;

$.ajax(feed, {
    accepts:{
        xml:"application/rss+xml"
    },
    dataType:"xml",
    success:function(data) {
        //Credit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943544/how-to-parse-an-rss-feed-using-javascript

        $(data).find("item").each(function () { // or "item" or whatever suits your feed
            var el = $(this);
            console.log("------------------------");
            console.log("title      : " + el.find("title").text());
            console.log("link       : " + el.find("link").text());
            console.log("description: " + el.find("description").text());
            });
        }   
    });

});
```

and this works for sites like http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/uk/rss.xml   but when I use a site like feed://feeds.skynews.com/feeds/rss/uk.xml I get ::FAILED_TO_LOAD_RESOURCE ..even if I remove "feed://".

I have tried setting headers in the ajax

```
headers: {"Origin": "*"}
```

but I am not sure how this works.

Is this a CORS problem? If it is how can I overcome this in NW.JS

I have also tried fetch() with the same results, the server refuses to send me data.

I would like to be able to retrieve any XML data from any RSS feed without having to use API's like rss2json etc to do that.

Comment: Most feeds are not likely CORS enabled. You could create a proxy on your own server

Comment: I have come across 4 out of about 20 I tried. It baffles me that some are. Is there a way to do this without using an external proxy server? Is there a way inside of NW.JS to create a proxy that resides locally inside the app itself for doing this?

Comment: Not really familiar with nw.js. Have always used server side proxies. There are also several third party proxy services but prefer to role my own and not rely on others

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that spoofing the user agent to Chrome (even though NW.JS is built on chrome!) makes it work. I used "Request" to do this.

```
var request = require('request');
    var options = {
      url: cleanURL,
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'
      }
    };
    function callback(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)     {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        console.log(body);
      }
    }
    request(options, callback);
```