# Script not displaying in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have made this code to prompt an RSS to my website with financial news:

```
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <ul>
    <!-- Replace the URL below with the URL of the RSS feed you want to display -->
    <script src="https://rss.app/feeds/<YOUR-YELLOWBLOCK-RSS-FEED-URL>.xml"></script>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But when I execute it, I think the script doesn´t work because I see the title but not the news themselves.

I am a rookie in this can someone help me?

Comment: `<script>` tag doesn't know what to do with the xml. If you want to display the content you'll have to parse it first. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10943610/3789527) for an example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you want a [list widget](https://rss.app/rss-widgets/list-widget).

Comment: Actually the list widget this hero suggest is exactly what I needed.